# Tag system bug?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

If I search for "dojo" on stackoverflow I'm taken to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo) which displays only a single result for the tag.

However if I go into that single [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296780/dojo-and-displaying-inline-svg) it clearly lists on the right hand side that there are (at the time or writing) 574 posts with the "dojo" tag.  If I then click on the tag again I'm taken back to the first page which announces that there is only one question with the dojo tag.

Am I missing something here?

UPDATE:
[image http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1440/capturexw.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1440/capturexw.png)

Now obviously the problem is that I happened to have been on the featured tab when I did the search, so it searched within the featured questions.  Just me being dumb.

Comment: Screenshots Meek, screenshot that mutha like you can't get enough of those freehand circles.

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo shows 573 results for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching maintains the current question type tab, in this case "featured".

Answer (score 1):

You're in the Featured tab. That will list all those questions tagged with such that have a posted bounty. As such, you'll see a far lower number than when on another tab view.

Click on the other tabs and you'll see larger numbers. [Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=dojo&sort=active&pagesize=50) or [Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=dojo&sort=newest&pagesize=50) are probably what you want.

That will/should then stick for future searches.

Answer (score 0):

If the keyword you searched is also a tag, it will be redirected to the Questions tab filtered with that tag (e.g. `/questions/tagged/{keyword}`).

Under the Questions tab, the selected sub-tab (stats/newest/featured...) will be default to your last selected one. So for your case, if you've searched from "Questions>Featured", meant your last visit to the questions tab is likely to be the "featured" sub-tab, hence your are redirected back there.

If you've searched for something that's not a tag, you will be brought to this path "`/search?q={keyword}`"